# Changing controls order in row class div bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Well, I'am building a web application that uses twitter bootstrap 3 , and supports both languages English and Arabic with two different  master pages for each,
am using `div` with class `.row` to put my controls inside
controls inside rows by default starts from left to right
when I change my website language to Arabic I want to reverse all items inside rows from right to left
am changing the master page with my stylesheet files, I've tried floating and directions but it never works for me for items inside div with `.row` class

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_TaskContent" runat="server" class="row">
                  <asp:Panel ID="pnl_TaskColumn" runat="server" class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="box-body">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <%--Task Name--%>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lbl_Task_Name" runat="server" Text="Task Name" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False"></asp:Label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil">
                                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator27" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                  ControlToValidate="txt_Task_Name" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="saveTask" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                          </i></span>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Task_Name" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <div class="input-group-btn">
                                              <asp:Button ID="button_tf" CssClass="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" runat="server" Text="Functions" data-toggle="dropdown" ValidationGroup="none" />
                                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                  <li>
                                                      <asp:Button ID="btn_AddTaskFunModal" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-block" runat="server" ValidationGroup="novali" Text="Add/Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addTaskFunctions-modal" /></li>
                                                  <li>
                                                      <asp:Button ID="btn_BrowseTaskFunModal" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-block" runat="server" ValidationGroup="novali" Text="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#BrowseTaskFunctions-modal" /></li>
                                              </ul>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <%--Task Status--%>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lbl_Task_Status" runat="server" Text="Task Status" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False"></asp:Label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-signal">
                                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                  ControlToValidate="ddl_Task_Status" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="saveTask" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                          </i></span>
                                          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Task_Status" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False">
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="N">New</asp:ListItem>
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="A">Active</asp:ListItem>
                                          </asp:DropDownList>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <%--Task Priority--%>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lbl_Task_Proirity" runat="server" Text="Task Priority" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False"></asp:Label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-flag">
                                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                  ControlToValidate="ddl_Task_Proirity" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="saveTask" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                          </i></span>
                                          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Task_Proirity" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control">
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="H">High</asp:ListItem>
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="M">Medium</asp:ListItem>
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="L">Low</asp:ListItem>
                                          </asp:DropDownList>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <%--Completion Rate--%>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lbl_Task_CompRate" runat="server" Text="Completion Rate" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False"></asp:Label>
                                      <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_Task_CompRate" ErrorMessage="0-100" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="100" MinimumValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="saveTask"></asp:RangeValidator>
                                       <div class="input-group">
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-flag">
                                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator31" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                  ControlToValidate="txt_Task_CompRate" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" ValidationGroup="saveTask"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                          </i></span>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Task_CompRate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control">0</asp:TextBox>
                                                                                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i><b>%</b>
                                          </i></span>
                                            </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

what i want that when i change the display order to rtl, is to change the controls inside my row

[image: When Direction From Left To Right]

[image: When Direction From Left To Right but controls are not showing as expected]

**When Direction From Left To Right but controls are not showing as expected**

Comment: It would help if you could provide an example on any online code editor.

Comment: @Hashem Qolam i've edited my post

Comment: Amer, please consider posting the HTML output rather than the ASP code. Also please clarify how you make the page direction RTL. Posing the relevant CSS code, if any, would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have unusable html in your post, so I can't test this, but last year I contributed to this old repository: https://github.com/carasmo/bootstrap-rtl/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.css

Has some useful code when you change direction. It's 3.1 but some of it still works well. You'll have to pick through it to see what you need to tweek.

Here's an example of the input-group fixes:

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/tipufu/1/edit

*Assumes*

```
body {direction:rtl}
```

**CSS for RTL:**

```
.input-group .form-control:first-child,
.input-group-addon:first-child,
.input-group-btn:first-child > .btn,
.input-group-btn:first-child > .dropdown-toggle,
.input-group-btn:last-child > .btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.input-group-addon:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-left: 0;
}

.input-group .form-control:last-child,
.input-group-addon:last-child,
.input-group-btn:last-child > .btn,
.input-group-btn:last-child > .dropdown-toggle,
.input-group-btn:first-child > .btn:not(:first-child) {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.input-group-addon:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.input-group-btn:first-child > .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.input-group-btn:last-child > .btn {
  margin-right: -1px;
}

.input-group-btn > .btn {
  position: relative;
}

.input-group-btn > .btn + .btn {
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.input-group-btn > .btn:hover,
.input-group-btn > .btn:active {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**SOME HTML**

```
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>
```